# Git ignore .htaccess file for test subdomain or better method?

Tags: git, apache, .htaccess, version-control

I've set up a subdomain - foo.bar.com - and repo'd the contents of bar.com/public_html to bitbucket and then cloned them to foo.bar.com/public_html so that I can test things without messing up the actual site. I've also copied the other directories outside of of public_html, but those are mainly tmp files and others things I won't need to change

I thought there would be various issues with doing this, but so far just about everything has worked as hoped. This is, of course, with exception to things like:

```
PassengerAppRoot /home/walkerneo/pyserver
```

The subdomain is in /home/walkerneo/dev and the actual site is in /home/walkerneo. The python passenger-wsgi server is in /home/walkerneo/pyserver. I would like to use the passenger-wsgi in /home/walkerneo/dev/pyserver for foo.bar.com

I could just change the .htaccess file, but then if I commit, push, and then pull with the main site, I'm then using the python server from foo.bar.com

Is there a way to use relative paths in the .htaccess file?

Like:

```
PassengerAppRoot ../../pyserver
```

Or

```
PassengerAppRoot %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/../pyserver
```

..or something along those lines?

If I just add the file to git's ignore list for the foo.bar.com repo, but not the bar.com repo, what happens when I push or pull from foo.bar.com, or push or pull from bar?

What I would want, if I NEEDED to ignore the file, would be:

1. Pushes from bar.com to bitbucket include changes to that .htaccess file, as does reverting to older commits on bitbucket.
2. Pulling from bitbucket into foo.bar.com won'y change the .htaccess file.
3. Pushing from foo.bar.com doesn't change anything about the .htaccess file on bitbucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's a cheap solution in Git, although ideally, you can figure out how to may the .htaccess file portable. If you change the .gitignore file, then (because it is versioned), it will propogate the *ignorance* to the other two repos.

However, if you change the .git/info/exclude file of the dev repo(which uses the same format as .gitignore, but isn't versioned), then the .htaccess file will be ignored there, and left alone elsewhere. That should work, haven't tried it, though.